# Getting client side validation to work with Telerik MVC Window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, telerik-mvc

I am using a telerik mvc window extension that is triggered from a custom template link in a telerik mvc grid.  The window is modal and it contains a form for editing data. After successfully implementing client side validation using a standard html page, I have been trying to implement it in the telerik mvc window.  I have not been able to do so successfully.  Is this possible?  Does anybody have a working example of this?

Thanks
Ozzy

Answer (score 2):

You need to load to page in an IFrame. To do this, make sure the url in LoadContentFrom method starts with http or https:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Window()        
.Name("Window")        
.LoadContentFrom("http://www.example.com")
%>
```

if you're using the Url.Action() helper to get the url, include the protocol parameter to get the full url.

E.g
Url.Action("action name","controler name", "http")   <--may also need to include route values or null route value dictionary.

To close to window, you'll need to make a call back to the parent view, try this:

1. add a bool isValid property to your model
2. if succesfully validated, reload the view with isValid equals true
3. onload:

   var isValid = '<%: Model.IsValid%>';

   if(isValid == 'True')
   {
   window.parent.$('#MyWindow').data('tWindow').close();
   }

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. First make sure you have your ViewModel property that needs validation  decorated with the appropriate attribute. Eg: [Required(ErrorMessage = "this is required")]

Then include all the client validation scripts found in telerik's folder in your application.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure you use the latest build of teleriks extensions. hth.